# Is it possible to run an OpenRefine script in the background?

Tags: openrefine

Can I trigger an OpenRefine script to run in the background without user interaction? Possibly use a windows service to load a OpenRefine config file or start the OpenRefine web server with parameters and save the output?

We parse various data sources from files and place the output into specific tables and fields in sql server. We have a very old application that creates these "match patterns" and would like to replace it with something more modern. Speed is important but not critical.  We are parsing files with 5 to 1,000,000 lines typically.

I could be going in the wrong direction with OpenRefine if so please let me know.  Our support team that creates these "match patterns" would be best suited with a UI like OpenRefine instead of writing Perl or Python scripts.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenRefine has a set of library that let you automated an existing job. The following are available: 
* two in Python [here](https://github.com/PaulMakepeace/refine-client-py/) and [here](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-python)
* one in [ruby](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-ruby) 
* one in [nodejs](https://github.com/pm5/node-openrefine)

Those libraries needs two inputs:

1. a source file to be processed in OpenRefine
2. the OpenRefine operation in JSON format.

At [RefinePro](http://refinepro.com/hosting/) (disclaimer I am the founder and CEO of RefinePro), we have written some extra wrapper to schedule  to select an OpenRefine project, extract the JSON operations, start the library and save the result. The newly created job can then be scheduled.

Please keep in mind that OpenRefine has very poor error handling which limits it's usage as an ETL platform.

Comment: In addition to the libraries mentioned by @magdmartin there is also a utility called "batchrefine" which provides methods to run OpenRefine in batch mode https://github.com/fusepoolP3/p3-batchrefine/blob/master/README.md